# Facebook Graph API explorer: get friends of friends

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to retrieve friends of a friend?
I'm using **SDK 1.0**.

For example, I get first my id to retrieve list of my friend

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/friends", userID ];
[QVFacebookQuery execute:query withHTTPMethod:@"GET" completion:^(BOOL success, id result, NSError *error) {
    /* print result if success */ 
}];
```

With this method I can retrieve list of my friend and relative user id.

If I use one of this id to query its friends, never works!

```
  .../user_id/friends
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported operation", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I've already read [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user/friends) and set up *user_friends* permission.

Answer (score 2):

You can´t get friends of a friend, for privacy reasons. You can´t even get all friends of the authorized user anymore - only those who authorized the app too.

Read more about the changes in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Is an SDK restriction only? Because I can view friend of my friend in Facebook application.

Comment: Exactly which application using what API call can you see a friend of a friend @Velthune

Comment: official Facebook application

Comment: You can get the mutual friend list between an authorized user and another arbitrary user. However you are right that you cannot get the full friend list of an unauthorized user.

Comment: the official facebook app can do a LOT more things than you would ever be possible to get with your own app

Comment: no, that´s actually since end of april 2014, check out the changelog. the api version is important, not the sdk version. you can´t use the v1.0 api in an app created after april 2014.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the mutualfriends endpoint. An example request would be of the form {user-id-a}/mutualfriends/{user-id-b}. So your query would be...

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mutualfriends/%@", firstUserID, secondUserID];
```

Note this will work for Graph API v1.0 but has been deprecated in newer versions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user/mutualfriends

Comment: mutual friends..  better than nothing!

Comment: do you have an app created before end of april 2015? because as he pointed out, mutual friends is deprecated, it does not work anymore in newer apps, that´s why i did not mention it.

Comment: The endpoint for the newer version of the api will find you the mutual friends list of your current user and another user of the app if they have both enabled user_friends permissions. It will not work between a signed in user and another arbitrary user though. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user.context/mutual_friends